# What's the best software for reading and writing image tags to and from image meta data fields?

Tags: metadata, import, export, photo-viewer

I have millions of images that have had image tags assigned to them by various cv-api's my plan is to generate a data file, that will associate the image file names with the data captured so that I can then import the data and images into a windows desktop application for verification and modification when needed. When complete I need to be able to export the images and a modified data file.

Your learned thoughts and opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExifTool has been mentioned, another tool for this job is [exiv2](https://exiv2.org/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

**Phil Harvey's [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/)** seems to be the perfect choice for such a task.

This is the most comprehensive image tag reader (and manipulator), and it has perhaps the most complete catalog of the known tags on the web. It's free and open source.

It's a command-line tool, so it must be easy to integrate it into your script.

```
> exiftool -*date* DSC_0904.JPG

File Modification Date/Time     : 2022:08:04 11:44:00+10:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2022:08:04 11:44:49+10:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2022:08:04 11:44:00+10:00
Modify Date                     : 2022:08:04 11:31:26
Date/Time Original              : 2022:08:04 11:31:26
Create Date                     : 2022:08:04 11:31:26
Sony Date Time                  : 2022:08:04 11:31:26
Create Date                     : 2022:08:04 11:31:26.872780+10:00
Date/Time Original              : 2022:08:04 11:31:26.872780+10:00
Modify Date                     : 2022:08:04 11:31:26.872780+10:00
```

Comment: I would suggest using `exiftool -Time:All file.jpg`, as that will display all Date/Time related tags in the file.  Using a wild card will skip a few tags that have only Time in the name but not Date

Comment: @StarGeek, you are right, but my point was rather to show how flexible ExifTool is with interpreting the command line arguments. I just chose the first thing that came to my mind and that was easy to understand.